# LM7805 Voltage Regulator stops working when input voltage increases

Tags: esp8266, linear-regulator, troubleshooting, 7805

I have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4jKIr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I designed the PCB, had it printed and now I am testing it.
When I power it up the following happens:

- When V1 stays below 27.8V circa, everything works fine. The WeMos board powers up, its led flashes as expected. Output voltage of the 7805 is 5V stable.
- When V1 passes the 27.8V, the output voltage of the 7805 drops to 1V circa, shutting down the board. The transistor base voltage oscillates around 0.7-0.8V, causing the relay to open/close very quickly.
- If V1 goes below 27.8 volts again the board powers up again and the relay stops flickering.

I tried to remove the WeMos board and put a resistor instead (with Q1 base floating), and in this case everything works perfectly fine, the 7805 doesn't switch off.
I am not an expert in troubeshooting circuits, so I'm asking for help.
What could be the problem? How can I start troubleshooting? Could it be the 7805 oscillates?

Edit: I installed a small aluminium Heatsink on the 7805 (TO-220 package). I calculated a maximum current consumption of 70 mA (there are some leds and another IC using the 5V), for a total power dissipation of circa 2W

Comment: what kind of a heat sink are you using? Are you sure the 7805 is genuine? (you're close to the absolute maximum input voltage of 35v for a legit part, so I can see a clone failing sooner). At any rate, consider using a DC-DC buck regulator (switching) instead of a linear regulator, to save power and heat (several watts).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added some information about the heatsink. I am not sure about the 7805, I may have bought it on AliExpress (can't remember). I'll try another ans I will also try the dc-dc buck solution.

Comment: run it with a fan blowing directly on the 7805's heatsink; if it gets better, you have an overheating issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly because of thermal shut-down. These kind of old linear regulators perform poorly when they have to go from such relatively high voltages down to 5V - there will be lots of heat no matter the load connected to it.

When thermal shut-down occurs, the output voltage from the IC drops just as you describe. Then when the part cools off, it goes back up again. This leads to oscillation.

You will absolutely need a heat sink, and you could fiddle around with various heat sinks in an attempt to stall the thermal shut down to higher input voltage levels. A less expensive and less problematic solution is to use a LM317 first, to take the voltage down to 15V or so, then place a 7805 "in series" after that.

This is how it was done "back in the days" when these parts were new and it is still ok for hobbyist solutions (or if you actually need heating to drive out moisture), but it isn't how professional designs are done any longer. You should strongly consider using a switching buck regulator instead.

Also, I don't understand your relay circuit. It says 5V relay, yet you feed it the 27V-something voltage. I'm not sure what those 4 resistors in parallel are supposed to do, current limiter? Looks very fishy, did you think they form a voltage divider somehow? You will need a 24VDC coil relay, and even then that coil won't be happy if you stray too far from the nominal voltage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was trying to use only components I have at home, so I measured the current consumption of the relay and as you said I used the resistors to form a voltage divider. Their equivalent resistance is 550Ohm, so at circa 50 mA they are supposed to drop 27-28 Volts. I tried the circuit on a breadboard, and it seems to work.

Comment: Instead of an lm317, i would use a 7815, maybe even a 7809 as well; chained. The tabs of 78xx's are GND, so they can all use the same heatsink, no mica or anything...

Comment: I did some tests. It is indeed the 7805 shutting down, and adding a bigger heatsink helped. I am also almost sure the component is not genuine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Enrico Voltage divider: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider. You need it to give close to the 5V coil voltage, or alternatively use a 24V relay.

Comment: @dandavis Well, I wouldn't use any of it, I would use a switch regulator :) They are easy enough to make nowadays, even for hobbyists. Just grab some reference design. I'm sure there's cheap hobbyist board-to-board ones with socket/headers that will be easy to use together with THR components. Or grab an eval board from a silicon vendor.